# How to insert Master-Detail without committing the Master first in Oracle?

Tags: javafx, oracle11g

I'm building a JavaFx app based on Oracle database 11g XE.

I'm trying to insert Master row the a detail to it, but I can't achieve this before committing the master first.
This is creating a problem in case I want to rollback if something went wrong, Because now instead of just rolling back I have to delete the invoice.

I created a test case app based on HR schema that contains the basic classes:

```
public class Database {

private static final String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String username = "HR";
private static final String password = "hr";
private static final String thinConn = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
private static Database database;
private static Connection conn; 

private Database(){        
        System.out.println("Databse loading ..");
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if(conn==null){
                    setconnection();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Database.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }                
        }).start();

}    
/* We create this static method so that all view share the same Database instance
*  While the constructor is private 
*  Now instead of calling "new Database();" from controllers we'll call "Database.getInstance();"
*/
public static Database getInstance(){
    if(database == null){
        database = new Database();
    }
    return database;
}

public static Connection setconnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(driver); // load Oracle driver
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(thinConn, username, password);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    return conn;
}   

public ResultSet execQuery(PreparedStatement stmnt) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery();
    return rs;
}

public ResultSet execInsert(PreparedStatement stmnt) throws SQLException{        
    ResultSet generatedKeys = null;
    stmnt.executeUpdate();
    generatedKeys = stmnt.getGeneratedKeys();
    System.out.println("Stmnt Executed");
    return generatedKeys;
}

public void execUpdate(PreparedStatement stmnt) throws SQLException{
    stmnt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Stmnt Executed");
    //Close statement
    stmnt.close();
}

public void commit() throws SQLException{
    conn.commit();
}

public void rollback() throws SQLException{
     conn.rollback();
}

public void rollback(Savepoint savepoint) throws SQLException{
    conn.rollback(savepoint);
}

public Savepoint setSavepoint() throws SQLException{
    return conn.setSavepoint();
}

public void releaseSavepoint(Savepoint savepoint) throws SQLException{
    conn.releaseSavepoint(savepoint);
}

public class InsertRollBackApp extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                int deptId = insertDept();
                //If you removed next line The application will hang and insert fail
                Database.getInstance().commit(); 
                insertEmp(deptId);
//                    Database.getInstance().rollback();
                Database.getInstance().commit();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InsertRollBackApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                System.out.println("Error Raised: "+ex.getMessage());                     

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error Raised: "+ex.getMessage());
                Logger.getLogger(InsertRollBackApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public int insertDept() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS("
              +" DEPARTMENT_NAME)"
              + " VALUES(?)";

    PreparedStatement stmnt = Database.setconnection().prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"DEPARTMENT_ID"});
    stmnt.setString(1, "DUMMY_DEPT");
    ResultSet rs = Database.getInstance().execInsert(stmnt);
    int DeptId = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
        DeptId = rs.getInt(1);
    }        
    return DeptId;
}

public void insertEmp(int DeptId) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES("
              +" FIRST_NAME,"
              +" LAST_NAME," 
              +" EMAIL,"
              +" PHONE_NUMBER,"
              +" HIRE_DATE," 
              +" JOB_ID,"
            + " DEPARTMENT_ID)"
            + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL),?,?)";

    PreparedStatement stmnt = Database.setconnection().prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"EMPLOYEE_ID"});
    stmnt.setString(1, "M");
    stmnt.setString(2, "G");
    stmnt.setString(3, "mg");
    stmnt.setString(4,"515.123.1111");
    stmnt.setString(5,"IT_PROG");
    stmnt.setInt(6, DeptId);
    Database.getInstance().execInsert(stmnt);
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Thank you for your time

Gado

Comment: Is `Database` supposed to be a singleton? Making everything `static` defies the purpose of a singleton. Furthermore initializing a non-volatile field from a seperate thread could also lead to problems. You may never see the new value from the other thread or probably worse the connection could be replaced ***at any time after the `Thread.start` method call in the `Database` constructor***. This means you could use a different connection with `insertEmp` and `Database.getInstance().commit();`.

Comment: @fabian Thank you for your response. Well in the previous swing version of my app i was using pure Singleton (One class with one static method returning a Connection. But i built this app following  a JavaFX taturial. I think the tutor used this method to separate the DB thread from the app thread. But what do you think what should i change?